# Extern function in interface

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to declare a `extern function` in an interface and implementing it in a separate file in an effort to make our testharness generic.

What i want is something like this:

*in_check.sv*

```
interface in_check;
  extern function bit fu_check(int num, logic state);
endinterface
```

*in_impl.sv*

```
interface in_impl(in_check uin_check);
  function bit uin_check.fu_check(int num, logic state);
    if(state) return num;
    else return 0;
  endfunction
endinterface
```

But Questasim gives me this error message:

```
** Error: (vsim-3787) in_impl.sv: Exported function 'uin_check.fu_check' arguments don't match those of export/extern task in interface 'in_check'.
```

[This](https://books.google.no/books?id=OgvkBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=systemverilog%20extern%20function%20-class%20-DPI&source=bl&ots=QqogKWJRco&sig=ZcJ26C05OZVb_58LAEiApVfD2BU&hl=no&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjboLDLo6jSAhXDXSwKHdrxDQcQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=systemverilog%20extern%20function%20-class%20-DPI&f=false) indicated that it should at least be possible with implicit declaration, but implicitly defined functions (i.e. `extern function fu_check`) gives this error message:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) in_check.sv(20): near "fu_check": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER.
```

Tasks work perfectly, and I can live with having to use an output argument. However, I would much prefer to be able to give a return value.

How can I make this work?

Bonus question: The LRM seems a bit light in info on this, is the implementation tool specific?

Comment: Will `include` help?

Comment: Hi Hida, I think you are pushing the envelope and will find this tool-specific.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I just finished testing this on your excellent [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com) and you are correct. While the Incisive and Riviera releases does not even support extern within interfaces, VCS handles this nicely. I suppose I'll have to take this up with Mentor.

Comment: I talked to John Aynsley about this. He thinks it has been in the language a long time to enable a task or function defined in a module (or an interface in your example) to be called from an interface (or in the LRM example from another module connected via the interface). He thinks this is a part of the language that is not often used and hence not well-supported. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Our white-box non-class based testbench (which supports several DUT-s) uses interfaces to define prototypes for tasks used in similarly DUT-neutral testcases. The tasks are then implemented in DUT specific interfaces. Quite a lot of hierarchy is involved (which also might confuse Questa) and it all involves a lot of probing and self-developed verification methodology. So in short, we are quite committed to this approach at the moment . On the assumption that Questa is lacking support for doing the same with functions, I'll be contacting Mentor support, and going with tasks for now.

Comment: How task can be used here, as I checked on edaplayground and it didn't work for me.